# function visibility

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Can someone explain to me why `external` is used in below code snippet?
A general clarification of how the visibility modifiers work in practice would be great, I've always understood that `external` meant that the function can only be called from outside the contract, yet this particular piece is a part of the contract, so wouldn't `internal` or `private` be the right one to use?

```
function finalizePresale() external onlyOwner {
    require (!isFinalized); 
    isFinalized = true;                          
    token.transferOwnership(owner);                            
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its private  finalizePresale would not be called outside the contract and if its internal they would not be called apart from the contract which created the function.

If you look at the function there is also a modifier which has OnlyOwner,I guess the intention is to expose the function outside the contract and make it accessible to only owner of contract for which external suits better.

Comment: Why would you want to expose the function to outside the contract if it's only the owner of the contract that has access anyway?

Comment: It's the only way you would be able to call this function. External means the function can only be called from outside the contract, for example from the web front-end. Being the contract owner doesn't mean you have access unless you explicitly code it that way.

For example, there could be a button on the website that upon click finalizes the presale, and the only way for it to work is if the one clicking the button is the owner of the contract.

Once you deploy the contract, being the owner doesn't mean anything unless you code the functions.

Comment: @ABGhostCoder : Assume a case where you have function that collects all ether and sends it to owner address, you never want that function to be called by all but only by owner of the contract ? If you don't expose such function without OnlyOwner modifier,then there would be no way out.

Comment: made sense, I tried making the function internal and then I couldn't call it from outside anymore. So external is used for one to be able to call it from outside, how do you choose between public/external and internal/private?

Comment: You can find the documentation here https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters .